# Batch: list available hard drives and work with chosen option

Tags: batch-file, cmd, volume, wmic

I would like to list all available, removable hard drives in a batch script and continue to work with the chosen option. I know there are options like

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,volumename
```

to list the hard drives and

```
SET /P M=Type 1 or 2 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO One
IF %M%==2 GOTO Two
```

to create a menu. But how do I store the volumes in variables and list them in a menu?

Something like:

```
Choose from list:

1) D:\Harddrivename1
2) E:\Harddrivename2

Enter option: 2
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Removable hard drives, USB drives, fixed drives etc. How do you determine which is which? You need to research which ever of those you require and find the method, then add it to the script by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48814407/edit).

Comment: Based on the comment you've made to rojo's answer, can you confirm that you are looking specifically for only USB drives? Can you also please explain what it is you need to do once the drive has been 'menu selected'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that'll let you create an array of drives that are not of type 3 (fixed):

```js
rem // populates arrayname, arrayname.length, and arrayname.ubound
:getRemovableDrives <arrayname>
rem // unset array if exists
for /f "delims==" %%I in ('2^>NUL set %~1') do set "%%~I="
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a %~1.length = 0, %~1.ubound = -1

rem // note: nested for /f loops convert UCS-2 encoded WMI results to ANSI
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%# in (
    'wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType <> 3" get caption^,volumename /format:csv'
) do for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%I in ("%%~#") do (
    set "%~1[!%~1.length!].caption=%%~I"
    set "%~1[!%~1.length!].volumename=%%~J"
    set /a %~1.ubound = %~1.length, %~1.length += 1
)

rem // Trick to make private variables public
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('set %~1') do (
    if defined %~1.ubound endlocal
    set "%%~I"
)
exit /b
```

Here's a full example illustrating how to use the function:

```js
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:begin
call :getRemovableDrives drives

if %drives.length% equ 0 (
    echo No removable drives found.
    exit /b 1
)

set choices=
echo Removable drives:
echo;
for /L %%I in (0, 1, %drives.ubound%) do (
    set "choices=!choices!%%I"
    echo(%%I^) !drives[%%I].caption! (!drives[%%I].volumename!^)
)
echo(X^) exit
set "choices=%choices%x"
echo;
choice /C %choices% /N /M "Press a number (or X to quit): "
set /a choice = %ERRORLEVEL% - 1

if not defined drives[%choice%].caption exit /b 0

echo You chose !drives[%choice%].caption! (!drives[%choice%].volumename!^)
goto :begin

goto :EOF

rem // populates arrayname, arrayname.length, and arrayname.ubound
:getRemovableDrives <arrayname>
rem // unset array if exists
for /f "delims==" %%I in ('2^>NUL set %~1') do set "%%~I="
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a %~1.length = 0, %~1.ubound = -1

rem // note: nested for /f loops convert UCS-2 encoded WMI results to ANSI
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%# in (
    'wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType <> 3" get caption^,volumename /format:csv'
) do for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%I in ("%%~#") do (
    set "%~1[!%~1.length!].caption=%%~I"
    set "%~1[!%~1.length!].volumename=%%~J"
    set /a %~1.ubound = %~1.length, %~1.length += 1
)

rem // Trick to make private variables public
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('set %~1') do (
    if defined %~1.ubound endlocal
    set "%%~I"
)
exit /b
```

Hopefully you can use this to get you started.  In case I guessed incorrectly about the drive type detection, [see this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> and find DriveType on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Not sure why but the script you provided immediately quits after testing..
When testing with `wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, volumename, description` the external drive shows up as type 3

Comment: @max07 If you `wmic logicaldisk get /value` do you see any properties you could use to distinguish your removable drive from fixed?  Maybe lit's suggestion of `MediaType = 11`?  Sorry, I don't have any removable drives with me at the moment for testing.

Comment: I just noticed, that only my laptop does not recognize the external hard drives. My workstations does and the script is working here. But on both PCs the MediaType is displayed as 12.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started. It is in PowerShell. It gets a list of all removable (non-floppy) drives and presents a list for the user to chose from. If there is only one drive, it does not present the menu.

There is much to be done. There is no range or error checking on the user's input. And, of course, it is not stated what you want to do with the drive.

```
$drivelist = @(Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "MediaType = 11")

if ($drivelist.Count -eq 0) { Write-Host 'There are no removable drives.'
} elseif ($drivelist.Count -eq 1) { $thedrive = $drivelist[0]
} else {
    Write-Host 'Removable drives'
    $i = 1
    foreach ($drive in $drivelist) {
        Write-Host $('{0}. {1} {2}' -f $i, $drive.DeviceId, $drive.VolumeName)
        $i += 1
    }

    $dn = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the drive number.'
    $thedrive = $drivelist[$dn - 1]
}

# At this point, $thedrive is a System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_LogicalDisk
# ready to be used for something.

$thedrive | Format-List * -Force
```