# How to return an array of values across ENDLOCAL

Tags: arrays, batch-file, return

I have two variable length arrays of values, TargetName[] and TargetCpu[], which I need to return across the ENDLOCAL boundary.  I've tried the following, but only the first value on the first array gets returned.

```
for /L %%i in (0,1,%MaxIndex%) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in (""!TargetName[%%i]!"") do (
        for /f "delims=" %%k in (""!TargetCpu[%%i]!"") do (
            endlocal
            set TargetName[%%i]=%%j
            set TargetCpu[%%i]=%%k
        )
    )
)
```

Below is a print of the values returned.

```
Number Targets: 3
TargetName[0]: "Computer1"
TargetCpu[0] : "x64"
TargetName[1]: "!TargetName[1]!"
TargetCpu[1] : "!TargetCpu[1]!"
TargetName[2]: "!TargetName[2]!"
TargetCpu[2] : "!TargetCpu[2]!"
```

I've read about everything I can find, but nothing I've tried works for a variable length array.

Comment: I might need more context before I'd feel comfortable posting an answer.  I can't tell why you're calling `endlocal` on every iteration of your `for /L` loop. Just as a possible general solution, you could leave delayed expansion enabled until finished populating the entire array, then expose the array at the end with a `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('set Target')` loop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48818214/1683264) demonstrates a working solution in a similar situation.  The difference is it uses an `if` test that skips `endlocal` on all iterations except the first.

Comment: Where is `setlocal` located?

Answer (score 6):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "MaxIndex=6"
call :CreateArrays
set TargetName
set TargetCPU
goto :EOF


:CreateArrays

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,%MaxIndex%) do (
   set /A TargetName[%%i]=!random!, TargetCpu[%%i]=!random!
)

rem Return the arrays to the calling scope
set "currentScope=1"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('set TargetName[ ^& set TargetCPU[') do (
   if defined currentScope endlocal
   set "%%a"
)
exit /B
```

Comment: This worked for me, I used the following form
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('set ArrayName[') do ( endlocal & set "%%a" )
Only question I have is, if ArrayName[ has no elements then do ( ) will not execute
Not sure the consequence, will delayedexpansion stay enabled forever ?

Comment: **1-** If there are no elements nothing bad happens. When the invoked subroutine ends, an _automatic_ `endlocal` is executed. **2-** Your code will fail if you have _more than one level_ of previous nested `setlocal` commands. You should always include the `if`

Comment: Thanks @Aacini , I thought the 1 meant something, now in my code I call it set "_myfunction_localscope=true"  also I put the if defined _myfunction_localscope endlocal   Outside of the forloop for catching it.   Example   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('set %_NSTA_ArrayOfNumber% 2^>nul') do ( 
 endlocal & set %%a 
 )
if defined _CopyArray_localscope endlocal

Answer (score 2):

```
set target>tempfile
rem insert your endlocal here
for /f "delims=" %%a in (tempfile) do set "%%a"
set target
```

the first `set` will list all variable names that start `target` into a tempfile.

Then execute your `endlocal`

then read each line of the file, which is of the form `name=value` and execute it prefixed by the `set` keyword.

Final `set` is to display results.

clearing up the tempfile isyour affair. Naturally, if you have other elements you don't want restored, you could use for instance

```
set targetname>>tempfile
set targetcpu>>tempfile
```